# DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest returns multiple results for GUID

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am writing software that integrates with Microsoft Active Directory.  Previously, we were searching for specific users with `DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest` using a query like:

```
var request = new SearchRequest("DC=corp,DC=spring,DC=lan", "(objectGUID=\71\ad\7d\cc\6e\fa\cc\4e\87\c5\b7\a8\5b\85\e7\36)", ...
```

However we found that it could be slow depending on the number of objects in the tree, so we switched to:

```
var request = new SearchRequest("<GUID=cc7dad71-fa6e-4ecc-87c5-b7a85b85e736>", "(objectCategory=*)", ...
```

In our test environment this worked and seemed to be executing faster, but our end users have been reporting issues.  I have gotten enough diagnostic information out of log files to determine that the problem is the new query is returning more than one Entry result where the software is expecting only one and that is all I have to work on at the moment.

Does anyone know what the source of the extra results might be?  My understanding was that an objectGUID should be unique in an Active Directory environment.

Update - Actual code:

```
SearchResultEntryCollection results = null;
try
{
    var request = new SearchRequest("<GUID=cc7dad71-fa6e-4ecc-87c5-b7a85b85e736>", "(objectCategory=*)",
        SearchScope.Subtree, new[] { "sAMAccountName", "objectGUID", "cn", "mail", "telephoneNumber" } );
    var response = this._connection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;

    if (response != null && response.ResultCode == ResultCode.Success && response.Entries != null)
    {
        results = response.Entries;
        return results;
    }

    errorMessage = response != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.ErrorMessage)
        ? response.ErrorMessage
        : "Unknown Error"
}
catch (DirectoryException e)
{
    errorMessage = e.Message;
}

//other error handling
```

Comment: Guid binding shuld return only one result as guid is unique. That is absolutely correct. Can you provide the code snippet you are using to find users? Also, one way is to trace/log attributes to determine what users you get. I use guid binding with searchrequest class by myself as a fastest way of user search and have never faced similar issue before. Anyway, please provide the result of your research.

Comment: The only legal way, how can it happen, is when the object attributes are divided into two entries, if the object is too big. Faced similar situation when worked with dirsync control. So first entry will contain first half of the object attributes, and the second entry - the second half correspondingly. Do you query the entire object with all its attributes, or limit the attributes scope?

Comment: @oldovets I am only looking for some attributes, namely: sAMAccountName, objectGUID, cn, mail, telephoneNumber

Comment: @bootsman `searching for specific users` - It's probably quite inefficient searching for every objectCategory if you only want to fetch user objects. I can't seem to make sense of the whole Base DN/Filter situation you've got between the two examples provided either. What do you expect to find and what are you actuelly ending up getting?

Comment: In my code I also set ProtocolVersion to 3 (located at LdapConnecton.SearchOptions) and added SearchOptionControl with SearchOption.DomainScope flag to search request. Also my code relies on PageResultRequestControl. Maybe this will help

Comment: @olovets I have ProtocolVersion set to 3 but when I was looking at that I found that ReferralChasing was set to 'Subordinate | External`  Could that be an issue?  We don't set this anywhere so it must be the default.  I ask because I noticed that the 'SearchOption.DomainScope' you mentioned prevents referrals from being generated.

Comment: @notjustme Aplogies for the earlier vagueness, I have updated the issue with much more actual code.  As far as the '(objectCategory=*)' filter is concerned, that is only there because an empty filter is not valid and I had no desire to filter my results as I was expecting only one: a person object with the objectGUID I am searching for.  Instead I am getting multiple results and since this is happening on a customer system I do not have access to, I do not know what the results are.

Comment: @bootsman May be the issue, but not sure.  You can assume in your code that all of the returned objects are duplicates (maybe partially duplicates), so scan each object in result for requested properties until you find all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there may be some other child objects underlying the user account that you are searching for. These child objects can have no GUID's, so the GUID of the parent gets inherited.

For example Exchange-Active-Sync-Devices (SCCM/InTune device associations):

[image: Example]

The solution is to add a search filter like

```
(&(objectClass=person))
```

and then you will only get the user account youre searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing a GUID LDAP bind using the `DirectoryEntry` class ?

If the code is only supposed to find a single entry in the AD, binding using that GUID might work better. Although you'd then have to retrieve all the object data.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<GUID=cc7dad71-fa6e-4ecc-87c5-b7a85b85e736>");
```